# Desktop Sandboxing Issue with Swift macOS

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox

I've been trying to write a Mac app lately, and have run into an issue. This is not overly major but it would be great to have a solution.

I have to load an image at runtime, specified by the user (so no, I cannot embed the image into the bundle as **many** alternatives suggest), and embed it into an NSTextView using NSAttributedText. The image loads fine from the Pictures directory (/Users/USERNAME/Pictures/IMAGE) etc, but not from the Desktop. I have checked the Capabilities tab in Xcode, and Read/Write is enabled for all of the available options:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEbVF.png)

Using FileManager, I have determined that the file definitely exists, but is not readable. Can I set this manually in the Entitlements file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The standard desktop is not accessible out of the box if the app is sandboxed. Only the standard `Downloads`, `Pictures`, `Music` and `Movies` folder are accessible with the corresponding entitlement.

There are two options to access the other folders but in all cases the **user** must choose them once

- Open/Save dialog for temporary access if the appropriate entitlement is set.
- A security scoped bookmark for permanent access but also in this case the user must first choose the folder once via Open/Save dialog and the security scoped bookmark must be created programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Seeing as this file is specified by link only (I'm writing a MarkDown renderer), the open/save panel isn't an option. But thanks for the help and quick reply.