# Issues updating/appending a string to the end of a file in Swift

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, filehandle

I am working on an app where I am trying to write data to a file.  Basically the user can set the save directory and then I want to be able to check to see if the file exists.  If it doesn't then create it and write the data. If it does exist I want to update/append a string to the end of the file. I have tried following many examples and guides online and it seems everyone is doing this differently. I apologize ahead of time if I am missing something super simple or if this has been asked a hundred times.

I have mostly been working off of this example with no success
[Append text or data to text file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift/27327385#27327385)

```
@IBAction func addVariance(_ sender: Any) {
    let csvString = "08-06-2019,10:00 AM,10:23 AM,23,Offline,Test"
    let directoryURL = URL(string: "/Users/username/Desktop/CSVtest")
    let fileURL = directoryURL!.appendingPathComponent("/variances.csv")
    let data = NSData(data: csvString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        var err:NSError?
        if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: fileURL) {
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(data as Data)
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        else {
            print("Can't open fileHandle \(String(describing: err))")
        }
    }
    else {
        var err:NSError?
        do {
            try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path), options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to run this function when there is a file in the folder named "variances.csv" I get "Can't open fileHandle nil".

I have tried break points and print() lines.  It doesn't seem to be getting past "if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: fileURL)" and I can't figure out why.  fileURL is not nil.

When I try running this function outputting to an empty directory I get.

"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “variances.csv” in the folder “CSVtest”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/username/Desktop/CSVtest/variances.csv, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c9eaf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}"

Comment: Use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`, not `URL(string:)`.

Comment: I changed it from URL(string:) to URL(fileURLWithPath:) on line 3 but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `Desktop` is not accessible out of the box if the app is sandboxed. Only the standard `Downloads`, `Pictures`, `Music` and `Movies`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51311426/584548

Comment: Is there anyway around that?  Can I give the app full disk access somehow?

Comment: If the app is sandboxed there is no workaround unless the user chooses the folder once in an open dialog and you set a security scoped bookmark.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need.  I already have the open dialog to select the save directory. Got any good resources for the security scoped bookmark?

Comment: [App Sandbox in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html)